# Laravel Voyager BREAD Image Edit and Delete Issue

Tags: laravel, voyager

I have ran into a problem with image upload using voyager BREAD System. If I delete or update an image using BREAD the old image not replaced or deleted. It is still in the storage directory. I was using latest version of voyager with laravel 5.5. Is there any solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `public function deleteBreadImages($data, $rows) {...}` anymore 
in **Laravel Voyager 1.2** class file 
`vendor/tcg/voyager/src/http/controllers/VoyagerBreadController.php`

After two days of googling same issue I figured out the Hard Solution...

in my case image field name is **img** and model name is **Company**
code is executed while the Model **BREAD** is updating

Works on **Voyager 1.2**
Hope it helps ))

```
use Storage;

class Company extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updating(function($model)
        {   
            // Check if Old File Exists
            $oldFileExists = Storage::disk('public')->exists($model->original['img']);

            // If Old File Exists DELETE it, else Continue Adding New Image
            if($oldFileExists)
            {
                //Get File Extension:: .jpg .png .gif
                $fileExt = substr(strrchr($model->original['img'], "."), 0);

                //If File is not .GIF
                if($fileExt != '.gif'){
                    // Delete Old Non-GIF Image
                    Storage::disk('public')->delete($model->original['img']);
                }

                // Find .gif , -static.gif Old Images And Delete
                else{

                    // filename-static.gif
                    $staticOld = str_replace($fileExt,"-static".$fileExt,$model->original['img']);
                    // Delete Old Image.gif
                    Storage::disk('public')->delete($model->original['img']);
                    // Delete Old Image-static .gif if Exists
                    if($staticOld) Storage::disk('public')->delete($staticOld);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey please check below file in your project's `vendor/tcg/voyager/src/http/controllers/VoyagerBreadController.php` directory

and check for this

```
public function deleteBreadImages($data, $rows) {...}
```

function at line number 403.

in this function find `$this->deleteFileIfExists($data->{$row->field});` make it un-comment and check.

may i hope this helps you